# How to set prototype of a custom object, to an object of the same type?

Tags: javascript, prototype

In the following code I have created two objects, one of which is of type **String** and other of type **Person**.
How do I set the prototype of **Person**, to an object of the same type. Just like the built in **String** Object.

```js
/* constructor function */

function Person(fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.fullname;
}
var john = new Person("John");

var str  = new String("Hi");


console.log(john.__proto__); /* {...} */
console.log(str.__proto__);  /* String {...} */
```

Comment: Works as expected here, look at your browser console

Comment: what is use case ?? u can extend to get property of  string

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is being set on the type and any instance of that type will share the prototype. From the example code I assume that console logging the __proto__ object is what is confusing. Take a look on the [MDN __proto__ page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) why you shouldn't use that.

In order to check the type of the object you can use one of the following:

```js
// With the following you will get the name of the class
console.log(john.constructor.name) // Log: Person

// With the following you will can check if the object is of a certain type.
console.log(john instanceof Person) // Log: true
```

You seem to be using older features of JavaScript. Keep in mind that JavaScript has block scope variables ([let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)) and [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (they use prototype under the hood).